# Function to upload images in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I tried to create a function to upload images and move them to a specific location but is not working and I cant find out the problem.

This is the function I have:

```
function actualizar_imagen($imagen_cargada){
    if($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'] != ""){
        $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
        $imagen_final = $fecha . $_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['tmp_name'], '../publico/img/' . $imagen_final);
    }
    return $imagen_final;
}

actualizar_imagen('poster_grande');
actualizar_imagen("poster_pequeño");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot1");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot2");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot3");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot4");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot5");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot6");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot7");
actualizar_imagen("screenshot8");
```

And this is the code the function is supposed to replace, which actually works:

```
if($_FILES['poster_grande']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $poster_grande = $fecha.$_FILES['poster_grande']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['poster_grande']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $poster_grande);
}
if($_FILES['poster_pequeño']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $poster_pequeño = $fecha.$_FILES['poster_pequeño']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['poster_pequeño']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $poster_pequeño);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot1']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot1 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot1']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot1']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot1);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot2']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot2 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot2']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot2']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot2);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot3']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot3 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot3']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot3']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot3);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot4']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot4 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot4']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot4']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot4);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot5']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot5 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot5']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot5']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot5);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot6']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot6 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot6']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot6']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot6);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot7']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot7 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot7']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot7']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot7);
}
if($_FILES['screenshot8']['name'] != ""){
    $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
    $screenshot8 = $fecha.$_FILES['screenshot8']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot8']['tmp_name'],'../publico/img/' . $screenshot8);
}
```

I can't find the mistake.

Comment: `not working` is not a useful error description. What happens or doesn't? Do you get any errors?

Comment: there is any error message?, what is the code of move_uploaded_file() ...

Comment: that actualizar_imagen() function of yours is odd. `$imagen_final` will be undefined if name is empty

Comment: There's no error, after the page is executed it sends me back to my home page but when I check again the image that was suposed to be uploaded was not.

Comment: @Rafael `move_uploaded_file()` is an inbuilt PHP function.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]);` inside the function to make sure the variable is being populated.

Comment: @Ben Fortune I just tried that and it gave me back some sort of indexed array: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "xfiles_g.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(27) "C:\Windows\Temp\phpB52E.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(60669) }....

Comment: It's really odd since the if-based code works...

Answer (score 0):

Do you call your function properly inside your script after submitting the image?
I mean something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="uploadImages.php">
   <!-- other inputs here -->
   <input type="submit" value="click" name="submit">
</form>
```

And in your uploadImages.php script:

```
<?php
function actualizar_imagen($imagen_cargada){
    if($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'] != ""){
        $fecha=date("Y_m_d_H_i_s_");
        $imagen_final = $fecha . $_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imagen_cargada]['tmp_name'], '../publico/img/' .  $imagen_final);
    }
    return $imagen_final;
}

//check to see if the form is submitted and call the function
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   actualizar_imagen($imagen_cargada);
} 
?>
```